# How to set column value as variable in msaccess php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

My query :

```
$att="select
      AttData.Rollno,AttData.Name,AttData.Year,AttData.sec,AttData.".$date." 
      from AttData where AttData.sec='".$sec."' and AttData.dept='".$dept."' 
      and  AttData.year='".$year."' and AttData".$date."='AB'  ";
```

my Database design view is

[image]

my error

> Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression 'AttData.sec='A' and AttData.dept='cse' and
>   AttData.year='IV' and AttData'02-07-2016'='AB' ''., SQL state 37000 in
>   SQLExecDirect in C:\wamp\www\sms1.7.16\repotdaygen_allyear.php on line
>   325 select invalid37000

Comment: yuour issue is probably `and AttData".$date."='AB'` which becomes `and AttData'02-07-2016'='AB' `. Not sure what you are trying to do but like this it's plain wrong. What is the name of the column handling 'AB' value ? (I can't open the image from work...)

Comment: You need a space in there

Comment: column name is '02-07-2016' and value are either AB or P

Answer (score 0):

try this ...I added square brackets around $date in two spots

```
$att="select
      AttData.Rollno,AttData.Name,AttData.Year,AttData.sec,AttData.[".$date."] 
      from AttData where AttData.sec='".$sec."' and AttData.dept='".$dept."' 
      and  AttData.year='".$year."' and AttData[".$date."]='AB'  ";
```